# Set datagrid column width to star in codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm currently trying to set the last column in a DataGrid to take up any remaining horizontal space in the grid by setting its width to star. Here is my current attempt:

```
dataGrid.Columns[10].Width = DataGridLengthUnitType.Star  // doesn't work
```

Anyone know if/how this can be achieved? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
dataGrid.Columns[10].Width = new DataGridLength(double value here for initial size, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
```